# In Perl how do sub hash tables work?

Tags: perl

I'm working on some Perl code and I'm trying to gain understanding as to what Perl is doing.

I'm stuck on the following hash table code:

```
$summary01{$myHash{'ConfigID'}}{'ConfigID'} = $myHash{'ConfigID'};
```

The variable `$myHash` contains a single database record.

This code is setting storing a summary of data from a sql query.

can someone explain what the `}}{` code is doing? Is this a multiple dimension hash table?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code

```
$summary01{$myHash{'ConfigID'}}{'ConfigID'} = $myHash{'ConfigID'};
```

can be rewritten as

```
my $configID = $myHash{ConfigID};
$summary01{$configID}{ConfigID} = $configID;
```

I.e. assuming the `$configID = 123`, this would add an entry to `%summary01` like

```
%summary01 = (
    ...,
    123 => { ..., ConfigID => 123 },
    ...,
);
```

The `}}{` sequence has no special meaning. This is just a lookup in a nested hash `$summary{ ... }{ ... }` where one of the hash keys is another hash lookup `$myHash{ConfigID}`.

Comment: Interesting how you managed to explain this without talking about _references_ at all. I do like the arrows `->` to make the nested refs more obvious, especially for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

Lets break `$summary01{$myHash{'ConfigID'}}{'ConfigID'} = $myHash{'ConfigID'};` down into something more long-winded:

```
# Observation: %$summary01 is a hash of hashes
my $foo = $myHash{'ConfigID'};  # $foo is a scalar value
my $bar = $summary01{$foo};     # $bar is a pointer, a copy of a reference
$bar{'ConfigID'} = $foo;        # .... and this is the actual assignment
```